# Event Fired Before Credit Card Processing Magento

Tags: magento, observers

I am having an issue where instead of applying a discount to the order total paid it is being added:
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s336/sh/25235cd6-d3aa-4ce9-ae66-d5cf5fe06bab/5f275834c32e757bb2c72492357fb878

My instinct is that the discount is being added prior to the credit card transaction.

I would like to see what is contained within the quote object prior to the credit card transaction.

I think this could best be accomplished through an event observer.

What is the event that I should be listening for?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Comment: I would agree.. I guess?